# Array object value not counting up in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem of some of my object values in my array do not show correct in my html site, it only shows the last number of the array in every .When i make a console log it shows the correct numbers its just in the table it wont do it. it did work before but now i doest not and i do not know what i did that ruined my code. I hope for some quick help that works.
[image: Website]

```js
function metric(tryk){
    for (var i = 0; i < death_row.length; i++) {
    if (tryk === "metric"){ 
        var testMetric = death_row[i].height;
        
    }
    if (testMetric === null){
        death_row[i].height = 0;
        death_row[i].weight = 0;
        
    } else{
        var klip1 = death_row[i].height.slice(0,1);

        var klip2 = death_row[i].height.slice(3,death_row[i].height.indexOf("'",i+2));
        var klip2tal = Number(klip2);
        //console.log(klip2);
        var regn1 = klip1 * 12;
        
        var regn2 = regn1 + klip2tal;
        
        var regn3 = regn2 * 2.54;
        console.log(regn3);

        var vaegt = death_row[i].weight/2.2046;
        console.log(vaegt);
    };
};

var tabel2 = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < death_row.length; i++) {
        tabel2+="<tr>";
        tabel2+="<td>"+death_row[i].first_name +" "+ death_row[i].last_name+"</td>";
        tabel2+="<td>"+death_row[i].age_at_execution+" år"+"</td>";
        tabel2+="<td>"+regn3+"</td>";
        tabel2+="<td>"+vaegt+"</td>";
        tabel2+="</tr>";
    }
    tabel2+="</table>";
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = tabel2;
};
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

Comment: Please add reproducible code in order to test.

Comment: Fix your example code, hard to figure out what the problem is from your description and show some of the data that you're trying to render.

Comment: I don't see the *metric* function being called anywhere.

Comment: the metric function are in the html <button type="button" onclick="metric('metric')">Metric</button>

Comment: @andtryk Please add a minimalistic working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have made a fiddle with the code
https://jsfiddle.net/andtryk/cf96vu3y/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `death_row` is globally available and you want to have unique values for `regn3` and `vaegt`, you'll need to save those to the individual row objects too.

```
var regn3 = regn2 * 2.54;
death_row[i].regn3 = regn3;

var vaegt = death_row[i].weight/2.2046;
death_row[i].vaegt = vaegt;
```

Then you can address them in your table the same way you display the other row values:

```
tabel2+="<td>"+death_row[i].regn3+"</td>";
tabel2+="<td>"+death_row[i].vaegt+"</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct HTML elements and add them to the document this way.

A `for...of` loop can set the `innerHTML` (or any property) of the elements as desired, using data from your array.

```js
const death_row = [
  { first_name: "first1", last_name: "last1", age_at_execution: "age1" },
  { first_name: "first2", last_name: "last2", age_at_execution: "age2" },
  { first_name: "first3", last_name: "last3", age_at_execution: "age3" }
];
const tabel2 = document.createElement("table");

for (let person of death_row) {
  let regn3 = "regn3 goes here"
  let vaegt = "vaegt goes here"
  const row = document.createElement("tr");

  const nameCell = document.createElement("td");
  nameCell.innerHTML = person.first_name + " " + person.last_name;
  row.appendChild(nameCell);

  const ageCell = document.createElement("td");
  ageCell.innerHTML = person.age_at_execution + " år";
  row.appendChild(ageCell);

  const regn3Cell = document.createElement("td");
  regn3Cell.innerHTML = regn3;
  row.appendChild(regn3Cell);

  const vaegtCell = document.createElement("td");
  vaegtCell.innerHTML = vaegt;
  row.appendChild(vaegtCell);

  tabel2.appendChild(row);
}

document.getElementById("test").appendChild(tabel2);
```

```css
td{ border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```